# Проблема с Selenium =(

Tags: парсер, selenium

хотелось бы узнать в чем моя ошибка

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


url = 'https://www.wildberries.ru/'

service = Service(executable_path='C:/chromedriver/chromedriver')  # указываем путь до драйвера
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

try:
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    wb_search = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'searchInput')
    wb_search .send_keys('iphone')
    wb_search .send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(5)

    goods = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-card')  # находим все товары на странице
    goods[0].click()  # выбор 1 элемента из списка товаров на странице
    time.sleep(5)

    """Вытаскиваем название, артикул, количество продаж и отзывов"""
    good_name = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-page__header')
    good_id = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'productNmId')
    good_sells = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-order-quantity')
    review = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-review__count-review')
    print(f'Название: {good_name.text}\nАртикул: {good_id.text}\n{good_sells.text} {review.text}')
    time.sleep(1)

    if int(review.text.split(' ')[0]) > 0:  # если отзывов более 0, то пролистываем страницу
        while True:
            browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,575)")
            try:
                """применим неявные ожидания, будем пролистывать, пока элемент не станет кликабельным"""
                WebDriverWait(browser, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Смотреть все отзывы'))).click()
                break  # как нажали элемент выходим с цикла
            except:
                continue
    else:
        print('У данного товара нет отзывов')
    time.sleep(3)

    feedbacks_list = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'comments__item')
    for feedback in feedbacks_list:
        autor = feedback.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'feedback__info').text.replace('\n', ' ')
        text_review = feedback.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p[itemprop="reviewBody"]').text
        vote = feedback.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'vote__wrap').text.split('\n')
        print(f'{autor}\nОтзыв:\n{text_review}\nОценка отзыва:\nположительно: {vote[0]}\nотрицательно: {vote[-1]}\n')

    browser.quit()
    
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
    browser.quit()
browser.quit()
```

Сама ошибка:

```
Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.126)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    (No symbol) [0x00ACE563]
    (No symbol) [0x00A57FC1]
    (No symbol) [0x0094CF10]
    (No symbol) [0x0097795E]
    (No symbol) [0x009770E5]
    (No symbol) [0x0099858C]
    (No symbol) [0x00972BFF]
    (No symbol) [0x00998804]
    (No symbol) [0x009AC9EB]
    (No symbol) [0x00998386]
    (No symbol) [0x0097163C]
    (No symbol) [0x0097269D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D69B82+2658722]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D5CB84+2605476]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B7825A+620666]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B76E80+615584]
    (No symbol) [0x00A605EC]
    (No symbol) [0x00A65958]
    (No symbol) [0x00A65A45]
    (No symbol) [0x00A7050B]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x765DFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77427A7E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77427A4E+238]
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Первая и очевидная ошибка — это использовать Selenium для парсинга. Этот инструмент для автоматизации тестов, а не для сбора данных.

Comment: как бы то ни было, практически на любом курсе изучается именно selenium

Comment: @DiMithras. a почему бы и нет?

Comment: @СергейШ во-первых, это не быстро. Во-вторых, сам грешил и использовал для парсинга динамических сайтов, но натыкался на ошибки, когда данные записываются по несколько раз из-за неправильных таймингов. Ну не для этого библиотека :) Есть же **requests**, для динамических **requests-html**, да и в конце-концов целый framework **scrapy**.

Comment: @DiMithras я вас прекрасно понимаю )) Вот видете, как вам помог селенимум в приобретений опыты ))

Comment: @Евгений попробовал запустить ваш код, пришлось, правда, вторую строчку поменять на `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys` и драйвер поставил **Firefox**, т.к. только он стоит сейчас. Отработало без ошибок.

Comment: @DiMithras сейчас попробую, спасибо

Comment: @DiMithras как пишут сами разрабы "Selenium - это инструмент эмуляции браузера, не обязательно инструмент для тестирования."

Comment: @СергейШ тоже верно. Но всё же для парсинга плохо подходит, ИМХО. Что ещё с ним можно делать помимо тестов… Ботов на web игрушки писать, наверное.